# Is there a way to automate hold and drag of an object with iOS automation?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, automation, ios-ui-automation

I am currently working on automating tests on iPad using a home built iOS automation framework running on sdk 5.0 and xcode 4.2. One of my test requires that I hold and drag an object. I am able to touchAndHold and drag separately but can't seem to find a way to combine these actions. I have not been able to find a solution for it on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

UIAElement has a method called. dragInsideWithOptions. The options include duration. Have you tried setting the duration to 1, then setting the rest of the drag options to meet your needs?

Comment: I've tried this but it simply taps on the object that i'm trying to perform a hold and drag action on.

Comment: Roderic thanks for your help. The following is the line of code i'm using.  `target.frontMostApp().dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.40,y:0.27},endOffs‌​et:{x:0.3,y:0.4},duration:1.0});`

Comment: @user1110780 I wonder if you tried adjusting your startOffset to x:0.4 and y:0.2 will this work? The docs say nothing about the extended decimal precision you are using but does mention support for 0.0 to 1.0.